# How should i route POST and GET in Mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I just started with routing in my web application and while i have read many tutorials on what routing is and how to write a `RouteConfig.cs` or use Attribute routing inside my controllers, very few tutorials really show how to handle a whole application.

Like most Asp.NET Mvc applications, when you scaffold your controller you get your create, edit, remove methods and you always have one to `GET` and one to `POST` .

But how do you handle the routing on these methods?

Say these are my Edit methods, what do i put on the post method for routing? And do i need to "fix" anything else for that routing to work when i click the "save" button?

```
   // GET: VehicleModels/Edit/5
    [Route("Aanbod/Edit/{id:int}")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        VehicleModels vehicleModels = db.VehicleModels
            .Include(v => v.Options)
            .Include(v => v.Fotos)
            .SingleOrDefault(v => v.Id == id);

        if (vehicleModels == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(vehicleModels);
    }

    // POST: VehicleModels/Edit/5        
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uploads)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var VehicleToUpdate = db.VehicleModels.Find(id);
        if (TryUpdateModel(VehicleToUpdate))

        // my code here

        return View(VehicleToUpdate);

    }
```

Comment: The `HttpPost` to Edit will need the same route as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using attribute routing, the GET and POST actions will both have the same route attribute. The only thing that might be different is if you name your routes, in which case, the name should only go on the GET version. You can't apply the same name to two different routes, even if they're effectively the *same* route.

Comment: I figured it would be something so simple and obvious that they would not mention it anywhere. Thank you